# Some projects not showing TFS Menus

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have 8 projects in my solution. 3 of them are not showing any TFS menus when I right click on the project or any of the files from Solution Explorer. They are in TFS though, if I go through the Source Control Explorer I can manually check them out/in. Also those 3 projects do not have associated .vspscc which the other 5 projects do. Something must have got messed up but I am not sure what. How can I fix this so that I get those TFS options back in Solution Explorer. Having to manually check out/in is not practical.

edit: I've tried wiping my local copy and bringing the solution down from source control again. I've also removed those projects from the solution and re-added them which did not work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like 3 of your projects have lost their source control bindings.  You should be able to restore them easily.  Just go to the Change Source Control dialog, which will allow you to set the source control bindings for all the projects in your solution:

> File > Source Control > Change Source Control...

Then you'll need to enter your TFS server name and the server path for the projects that have lost their bindings.

Answer (score 2):

Edward got me pointed in the right direction, for me it was an issue of TFS having gone offline.

Resolution: I selected the Solution level in Solution explorer, then went into **File>Source Control>** and selected the **Go Online** menu option, which restored all of my right click TFS menu options.